# Interoperacionalidade FORTRAN e C

Tags: c, fortran

Cada linguagem tem caractéristica que a fazem única, isso é fato! Contudo, como trabalhar com código `C` em `FORTRAN` e vice-versa?
É possível inserir o código `FORTRAN` no `C` com a diretiva `# include <>`?

Answer (score 5):

É possível "misturar" C e Fortran, mas não no mesmo ficheiro, nem directamente nem através de `#include`.

Vê, por exemplo, em http://www.cae.tntech.edu/help/programming/mixed_languages

A ideia básica é criar ficheiros com as funções apenas compiladas. Essas funções compiladas tanto podem vir do C como do Fortran.
Depois é fazer a linkagem (a união) dos ficheiros .o num executável.